# Disable autostart for SaltStack master/minion on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, salt-stack

I have set up two virtual machines (master and minion) to test salt scripts locally before deploying to live. For debugging purposes I would like to be able to start *salt-master* and more importantly *salt-minion* manually.

I already have removed all salt related files from */etc/init/* and */etc/init.d/* but after rebooting *ps aux | grep salt* still shows *salt-master* and *salt-minion* running.

Where else do I have to change?

Output on the minion:

```
root      1101  0.1  6.5 205652 67032 ?        Ss   11:39   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/salt-master
root      1111  0.0  5.6 170596 57416 ?        Ss   11:39   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/salt-minion
root      1219  0.1  6.4 585296 65264 ?        Sl   11:39   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/salt-minion
root      1243  0.0  5.7 287324 58744 ?        Sl   11:39   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/salt-master
root      1248  0.0  5.9 287324 60180 ?        Sl   11:39   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/salt-master
root      1261  0.2  6.3 298124 64936 ?        Sl   11:39   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/salt-master
root      1267  0.0  5.7 205660 57960 ?        S    11:39   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/salt-master
root      1270  0.0  5.8 582516 59032 ?        Sl   11:39   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/salt-master
root      1272  0.1  6.8 904132 69300 ?        Sl   11:39   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/salt-master
root      1279  0.1  6.8 904132 69292 ?        Sl   11:39   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/salt-master
root      1280  0.1  6.8 904132 69308 ?        Sl   11:39   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/salt-master
root      1285  0.1  6.8 904128 69296 ?        Sl   11:39   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/salt-master
root      1290  0.1  6.8 904132 69300 ?        Sl   11:39   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/salt-master
```

Output on the master (salt):

```
root      1092  0.8  6.5 205652 66896 ?        Ss   11:46   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/salt-master
root      1249  0.0  5.7 287324 58256 ?        Sl   11:46   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/salt-master
root      1251  0.0  5.8 287324 59232 ?        Sl   11:46   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/salt-master
root      1260  0.2  6.2 297212 63564 ?        Sl   11:46   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/salt-master
root      1262  0.0  5.7 205660 58172 ?        S    11:46   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/salt-master
root      1265  0.7  5.7 582516 58620 ?        Sl   11:46   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/salt-master
root      1275  0.8  7.1 904792 72780 ?        Sl   11:46   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/salt-master
root      1278  0.7  7.0 904568 71532 ?        Sl   11:46   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/salt-master
root      1284  0.7  7.0 904608 72072 ?        Sl   11:46   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/salt-master
root      1292  0.7  7.0 904056 71176 ?        Sl   11:46   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/salt-master
root      1303  0.7  7.0 904576 72144 ?        Sl   11:46   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/salt-master
```

Versions:
Ubuntu 16.04
salt-minion 2015.8.8 (Beryllium)
salt-master 2015.8.8 (Beryllium)

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 uses systemd. Try `systemctl disable salt-minion` instead.

Comment: In case anyone stumbles upon this - I had the opposite problem with the latest salt-minion 2016.3.1 but `systemctl enable salt-minion` fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @helmbert correctly mentioned Ubuntu 16.04 uses systemd. This means it doesn't rely on the scripts in /etc/rc* and /etc/init.d. To control services autostart you should use `systemctl` command.
That said to disable salt minion autostart:
`systemctl disable salt-minion`
and to disable master autostart:
`systemctl disable salt-master`